# When using expo to build a react native project, the ios screen is shortened and cannot be displayed normally on the Android simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

When using expo 49 scaffolding to build a react-native navigation project, NavigationContainer in @react-navigation/native and createStackNavigator in @react-navigation/stack are used to build routing. However, after the creation is completed, the corresponding ios load cannot be displayed in full screen, and the android emulator cannot be displayed normally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Wcd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0KvO.png)

Navigation Route

```
// import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Categories from "../screens/Categories";
import CategoriesMeal from "../screens/CategoriesMeal";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MainNavigator() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Categories}></Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen name="Meal" component={CategoriesMeal}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export default function Navigation() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MainNavigator/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
};
```

App.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Navigation from "./navigations/MealNavigatorConfig";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Navigation/>
      <Text>Open up App.1js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Categories Screen

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, View,Text} from "react-native";

const Categories = (props)=>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
                Categories Screen
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default Categories;
```

CategoriesMeal Screen

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

const CategoriesMeal = (props) =>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
                CategoriesMeal Screen
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
export default CategoriesMeal;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-reciepts-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried many ways like lower the routing version to solve this problem, but in the end I couldn't solve it. I don't know what caused this and what method I should use to solve it?